# Put readonly attribute on TextBox Control in markup?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a TextBox control and I want the rendered input element to have the `readonly` attribute with value `readonly`:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

I could do it in code-behind using the following code:

```
textBox.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly"
```

but I'd rather have all my control attributes and their values in my markup. Can I do it in the markup?
A solution could be to extend the TextBox control, but this feels overly complicated for the intended result.

I want to be able to change the value client-side with javascript, and read the value server-side during postbacks. Please note that putting the `TextBox.ReadOnly` property to `True` would *not* solve the issue, as this also causes the server to ignore the TextBox' value on postbacks. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx).) I simply want the readonly behavior from the browser.

Comment: maybe I'm mistaken, but doesn't asp.net just output all attributes that you add? Have you tried just adding it in design and see if it ends up in the output of the page? I believe it actually might as I sometimes accidently write "class" instead of "CssClass" and it just adds the class attribute fine.

Comment: @Bazzz: I tried that, but markup attributes in ASP.NET are not case-sensitive, so it throws an error because it expects a stringified boolean for the `TextBox.ReadOnly` attribute.

Comment: Good point, I didnt think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can't do it cleanly in the markup without getting ASP.NET's `ReadOnly` side effects.

However, you could use inline code, although it looks ugly.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox" />
<% textBox.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly"; %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following creates a readonly textbox where the value of the text is available to the codebehind.

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" Text="One Two Three" ReadOnly="true" />
```

Code Behind (C# for this example):

```
string someText = string.Empty;
if (Page.IsPostBack)
    someText = Text1.Text;
```

Comment: Not during postbacks. See the MSDN article I linked in the question.

Comment: Then you're not clear on what you're unable to accomplish using this method. The server will not allow the client to change the value, but the value is still available to the server.

Comment: @Jim: Crikey, you're correct. I want to change the value client-side with javascript.

Comment: Then use javascript to set the readonly attribute of the textbox at load time. For instance using JQuery's $(document).ready()... $('#selector').val('I changed!').attr('readonly', 'readonly') will survive the postback.

Answer (score 0):

youre only solution then is to use js.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use a Hidden Field.
As you change the value of the **ReadOnly TextBox** in javascript, change the value also of the **Hidden Field** and then access the value of the Hidden Field in the Server Side